# Phonegap Downloader Plugin, save data to /data folder

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am developing an application for Android using jquery-mobile and phonegap.
I'm using a [Downloader Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/Downloader), in order to download some files from a remote server.

I've installed the plugin and called it as recommended in the documentation:

```
window.plugins.downloader.downloadFile("http://server/file.txt", {overwrite: true, dirName: 'sdcard/MyFolder'}, 
      function(res) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(result));
    }, function(error) {
        alert(error);
    }
);
```

It's working great so far.

What I want to do is save the downloaded data under the root directory. Specifically in the data folder (`/data/MyAppData`). Is it possible using this plugin?

Other solutions to achieve this functionality are also welcome (eg. using phonegap's File API)

Comment: You have the source to the downloader plugin, so you should be able to make it do that.